# Get element by not having an id/class

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I want to select all elements that don't have a specific class, how can I do this ?
I would like to have something like :

```
var test = document.getElementsByClassName(!"class");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll(":not(.class)");
```

But you'd better be a little more precise, for example targeting only divs:

```
var test = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(.class)");
```

Comment: I wanted to select all the <td> in a specific table, and I did it with var test = document.querySelectorAll("#id td:not(.troupe)"), and it works